# How to merge a single commit from one branch to another without changing the commit ID (SHA)

Tags: git, merge, cherry-pick

I acknowledge that there are similar questions that have been asked and answered here. Since none of them give me definite answers, I thought asking this question here again. Hope you don't reject this question. With that said:

### Scenario

We have a Bitbucket dev branch that stores content related to a specific release (Let's call the branch **dev-release-1**). Since the next release work starts before the current release is GR, we created another branch for the next release (let's call this branch **dev-release-2**). It means some people continue to work on the **dev-release-1** while working on the new branch. The new branch should have the changes being made in the current release branch as well. The changes in the **dev-release-1** branch are minimal and we want to avoid a full merge of **dev-release-1** to **dev-release-2**.

### Questions

1. Is cherry-pick a good option for this scenario? I tried this in our sandbox. Kind of works. Not sure if it will cause a lot of conflicts when we merge all branches into the master. Since cherry-pick results in an entirely new commit ID, I am not sure about it.
2. Is apply patch a good option? Tried this as well. Comparatively easier to do it with sourcetree. Since it results in an entirely new commit ID, I am not sure about it.
3. Is there an option to merge a single commit from one branch to another without changing the commit ID?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an option to merge a single commit from one branch to another without changing the commit ID?

Not that I know of: the parent of the commit changes, hence its SHA1.
So cherry-pick is one option: you need to test the final merges to master to see if merge conflicts are increased in this case.